# Can you please tell the Exception flow in below program

Tags: java

```
public void shape() throws ArithmeticException  {       
        try{            
            int i=2/0;                      
            throw new ArithmeticException();            
        }catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("catch "+e);
        }
    }
```

please tell me the flow of Exception

Comment: Surely you can discover that for yourself in a debugger?  That's the fun of programming, trying things and seeing what happens.  Good luck

Comment: Yes Micky. I debugged the code. but was littlebit confused.thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
public void shape() throws ArithmeticException  {       
    try{            
        int i=2/0;  //here exception will be thrown                    
        throw new ArithmeticException(); //this line will never be executed           
    }catch(ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("catch "+e);
    }
}
```

Exception will be thrown from line containing `2/0`, so it will happen before `throw new ArithmeticException();`. Then it will be handled by your `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

It'll throw an `ArithmeticException` with the message `"/ by zero"` on the line with `int i=2/0`.

Your catch block will catch that thrown Exception before you throw your own custom ArithmeticException.